# Прогрессбар круговой и его заполнение

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Есть код. Он заполняет круги прогресса. Такая проблема: мне нужны четыре круга с разной степенью заполнености. Подскажите, пожалуйтса, как это сделать? Не копировать же код для нескольких классов...

```
const circle = document.querySelector(".progress_ring_circle_1");
const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;

function setProgress(percent) {
  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

setProgress(20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать класс, который будет отвечать за это:

```
function CircleProgressBar(element) {
    this.element = element;
}
CircleProgressBar.prototype.setProgress = function(currentProgress) {
  ///.....
}
```

А затем юзать вот так:

```
const progress = new CircleProgressBar(document.querySelector(".progress_ring_circle_1"));
progress.setProgress(20)
```

Comment: Я тут не уточнил что внутри функции `setProgess` ты можешь спокойно получить исходный элемент через `this.element`. шаг №2 это сделать еще один класс, который будет хранить эти твои 4 элемента.